MySql creating some tables and some not
The client wants us to use Mysql for his ecommerce website and as we are doing with the backend. For now I'm using mysql and when about to deployment we will migrate to some provider
This is the sequlize snippet of how we are initializing the db
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

// Create a Sequelize instance
const sequelize = new Sequelize("[db_name]", "[username]", "[password]", {
  host: "localhost", // Replace with your MySQL host, e.g., '127.0.0.1'
  dialect: "mysql", // Choose the database dialect (MySQL in this case)
  port: 3306, // Default MySQL port is 3306

  // Pool configuration used to manage connections
  pool: {
    max: 5, // Maximum number of connection in pool
    min: 0, // Minimum number of connection in pool
    acquire: 30000, // Maximum time (ms) that pool will try to get connection before throwing error
    idle: 10000, // Maximum time (ms) that a connection can be idle before being released
  },

  // Optional logging configuration (can be a function or boolean)
  logging: false, // Set to 'console.log' to see SQL queries
});

// Test the connection
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
  });


module.exports = sequelize;

Previously I was not interesting in hard-coding the preferences models inserted in some models but just to make the models and use them as they should but it was not helping anyhow also moreover only the preference model which is initialized in some models are not created
require("dotenv").config();
const sequelize = require("../config/database"); // Assuming you've created the Sequelize instance in config/database.js
const User = require("../models/user");
const Address = require("../models/address");
const Merchant = require("../models/merchant");
const Product = require("../models/product");
const Cart = require("../models/cart");
const CartItem = require("../models/cartitem");
const Order = require("../models/order");
const Review = require("../models/review");
const Wishlist = require("../models/wishlist");

const setupDB = async () => {
  try {
    // Test the MySQL connection using Sequelize
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log("\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m", "✓ MySQL Connected!"); // Green color for success message

    // Sync the models with the database
    await sequelize.sync({ alter: true }); // Change to { force: true } if you want to drop existing tables
    console.log("\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m", "✓ Database tables synced!"); // Success message for syncing

    // Set up associations
    User.hasMany(Address, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "addresses" });
    Address.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "users" });

    Merchant.hasMany(Product, { foreignKey: "merchantId", as: "products" });
    Product.belongsTo(Merchant, { foreignKey: "merchantId", as: "merchants" });

    User.hasMany(Cart, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "carts" });
    Cart.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "users" });

    Cart.hasMany(CartItem, { foreignKey: "cartId", as: "items" });
    CartItem.belongsTo(Cart, { foreignKey: "cartId", as: "carts" });
    CartItem.belongsTo(Product, { foreignKey: "productId", as: "products" });

    User.hasMany(Order, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "orders" });
    Order.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "users" });
    Order.belongsTo(Cart, { foreignKey: "cartId", as: "carts" });

    Product.hasMany(Review, { foreignKey: "productId", as: "reviews" });
    Review.belongsTo(Product, { foreignKey: "productId", as: "products" });
    User.hasMany(Review, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "reviews" });
    Review.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "users" });

    User.hasMany(Wishlist, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "wishlists" });
    Wishlist.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "users" });
    Wishlist.belongsTo(Product, { foreignKey: "productId", as: "products" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      "\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m",
      "✗ Unable to connect to the database:",
      error
    ); // Red color for error message
    return null;
  }
};

module.exports = setupDB;

Also I want some help as im using hostinger (I don't want to but my boss wanted to use the hostinger for some reason) now I want to deploy  mysql db online so what can I use for it?

workbench is a gui for MySQL no database

User.hasMany(Wishlist, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "wishlists" });
Wishlist.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "userId", as: "users" });
Wishlist.belongsTo(Product, { foreignKey: "productId", as: "products" });

// Sync the models with the database
await sequelize.sync({ alter: true });

sequelize.sync() call move to below Associations.
